# Rails : A model does not have table, A table does not have Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

A model does not have table, A table does not have Model

Example:

*A model called **User**, but do not have **users table**...
A table called **products**, but do not have **Product*** model.

In this above case, can we access a data of products from the User.rb?.. if yes, how?

Cheers!

Comment: another question you ask but you didn't take time to accept the previous

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Why would you not have a users table? Why would you not have a product model. Which version of rails you using? Please accept some previous answers.

Comment: If your model has no table, just don't derive from `ActiveRecord::Base`.

Answer (score 2):

I would create a Model for `products` for many reasons....
However, if you really want to do that, I think you can use Raw SQL queries:

Something like: `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all('SELECT * FROM products')`

I hope it helps...